# Paralleize R raster merging

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster, rgdal

I have several Raster image tiles in GeoTiff Format and I want to merge to one big raster file.
It works like this, but it takes forever. Can I parallelise this or can I do it with GDAL?

```
  rasterlist<- list.files(path = "S2/20180326/ndvi/",pattern = ".tif$",full.names = T)

  tiles <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(rasterlist))

  for (i in 1:length(rasterlist)) {
    temp <- stack(rasterlist[i])
    tiles[[i]]<- temp
  }
  merged_raster <- do.call(merge,tiles)
```

Comment: Which is the time consuming part: the for loop or `do.call(merge,tiles)`?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to speed it up a bit with `lapply`, it replaces your loop in this situation:

```
rasterlist<- list.files(path = "S2/20180326/ndvi/",pattern = ".tif$",full.names = T)
tiles <- lapply(rasterlist,FUN=stack)
merged_raster <- do.call(merge,tiles)
```